# How to pass an object value into another object JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, javascript-objects

Let me tell you what am I trying:

I set a global object of user id to pass it into addpipe plugin JavaScript.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var providerId = {'pass_id':'<?php echo $providerInfo->wp_user_id; // provider id value is 5 ?>'};
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

Now I trying to get it in plugin JavaScript like so:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

alert(providerId.pass_id);
var size = {    
    width: 640,        
    height: 510    
};

var flashvars = {    
    qualityurl: 'avq/480p.xml',    
    accountHash: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',    
    showMenu: 'true',    
    lang: 'translations/en.xml',    
    mrt: 20,    
    payload: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,588,5, providerId.pass_id'    
};
```

The `providerId.pass_id` is giving correct value 5 in alert popup but in the payload it is going null.
I am getting payload in PHP like this:

```
$payload = explode(',', $json->data->payload);    
$accountHash = filter_var($payload[0], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);    
$userId = filter_var($payload[1], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);    
$postId = filter_var($payload[2], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);    
$providerId = filter_var($payload[3], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

If I set static value instead of this then everything is fine and it is also giving correct value in alert.

So please help me why `providerId.pass_id` is null when I am passing it in plugin JavaScript object.
Let me know if I miss something.

Answer (score 1):

Just concatenate the `providerId.pass_id` with the string in the payload part of the `flashvars` object like below. Currently you are just setting payload to the string `'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,588,5,providerId.pass_id'`, Where `providerId.pass_id` is literally a string and not a reference to the object value that you're after.

```
var flashvars = {
  qualityurl: 'avq/480p.xml',
  accountHash: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  showMenu: 'true',
  lang: 'translations/en.xml',
  mrt: 20,
  payload: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,588,5,'+providerId.pass_id
};
```